# How to make automatic backups of mysql db´s on Goddady with Apache servers

Tags: mysql, bash, cron

Im trying to automate a daily backup of mysql database on a shared hosting with Godaddy.com using Apache servers.

For this I researched and found out about bash scripts.

Goddady hosting lets me do cron jobs also so I did the following:

My bash script looks something like this (I masked the sensible data only):

```
<br>
#/bin/sh<p></p>
<p>mysqldump -h myhost-u myuser -pMypassword databasename > dbbackup.sql<br>
gzip dbbackup.sql<br>
mv dbbackup.sql.gz _db_backups/`date +mysql-BACKUP.sql-%y-%m-%d.gz`<br>
</p>
```

I configured the cron job which points to this file and executes it every 24 hours.

I have the cron job utility configured to send me a log message to my email every time it runs.

And this is the log message:

> /var/chroot/home/content/01/3196601/html/_db_backups/backup.sh: line
> 1: br: No such file or directory
>
> /var/chroot/home/content/01/3196601/html/_db_backups/backup.sh: line
> 3: p: No such file or directory
>
> /var/chroot/home/content/01/3196601/html/_db_backups/backup.sh: line
> 4: br: No such file or directory
>
> /var/chroot/home/content/01/3196601/html/_db_backups/backup.sh: line
> 5: br: No such file or directory
>
> /var/chroot/home/content/01/3196601/html/_db_backups/backup.sh: line
> 6: /p: No such file or directory

Its like it doesn't understand the language. Should I edit my .htaccess file for this?
Any ideas?

Comment: FWIW... I also tried without the tags... same result.

Comment: `bash` definitely won't like the HTML tags so remove them. I find it difficult to believe that removing the tags produced exactly the same result.

Comment: You are right, Its not "exactly" the same results. Now the log says: /var/chroot/home/content/01/3196601/html/_db_backups/backup.sh: line 1: �� command not found
mv: cannot stat `dbbackup.sql.gz': No such file or directory

Comment: Your `mv` command is complaining that it can't find the compressed output from `gzip`. I'm not sure what your operating environment is (i.e. what your working directory is, and whether you have write permission to it). It's possible that the file is either not being created, or it is, but not where you expect it to be, or your working directory is not as you expect.

Comment: Yes I have write permissions on that folder. And it seems to be that I have no idea where the compressed file is being saved so That may be part of the problem. What do you suggest?

Comment: Oh and the server is running under Linux

Answer (score 1):

Remove those html tags from the bash script, error messages are all related to them . Your script should be as the following.

```
#!/bin/sh
mysqldump -h myhost-u myuser -pMypassword databasename > dbbackup.sql
rm -rf dbbackup.sql.gz
gzip dbbackup.sql
mv dbbackup.sql.gz _db_backups/`date +mysql-BACKUP.sql-%y-%m-%d.gz`
```

Comment: I removed the tags and this is what the log says now: /var/chroot/home/content/01/3196601/html/_db_backups/backup.sh: line 1: �� command not found
mv: cannot stat `dbbackup.sql.gz': No such file or directory

Comment: All right I corrected the first line please retry with #!/bin/sh

Comment: Also I think you are running the script in the wrong folder. Your log says you are already in _db_backups . You should run it in one folder above.

Comment: Ok I changed the first line as you said. Also I moved the bash file one folder above. The resulting log is: /var/chroot/home/content/01/3196601/html/backup.sh: line 1: ��!/bin/sh: No such file or directory
gzip: dbbackup.sql.gz already exists;    not overwritten
mv: cannot stat `dbbackup.sql.gz': No such file or directory

Comment: I have added one more line to code. did you try it?

Comment: Ok I added the line and here´s the log: /var/chroot/home/content/01/3196601/html/backup.sh: line 1: ��!/bin/sh: No such file or directory
gzip: dbbackup.sql.gz already exists;    not overwritten
mv: cannot stat `dbbackup.sql.gz': No such file or directory

Comment: Never mind guys. I decided to make a PHP page which handles the script and its working fine this way. Apparently bash files are not supported.

Comment: @azirion  I'm trying to accomplish the same thing.  Would you please post your PHP script?